# Is accessing __dirname within function in Node.js considered as impure code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

If I have a function:

```
function testDirectory(filePath) {
    return __dirname === path.dirname(filePath);
}
```

Can I call this a pure function? By definition of pure function,

1. It doesn't cause any observable side effect.
2. It always evaluates the same result for same input value.
3. Both the criteria mentioned above are satisfied.

**However,** depending on where this function is defined, the result changes. So, in a way it is dependent on context (**location** in this case.)

Comment: Yes because it depends on external factors like the dirpath. I suggest you post this question in codereview stackexchange

Comment: I'd second what @SharjeelAhmed said - by your definition of purity, this function wouldn't meet the second criteria, as it will evaluate differently depending on where the code is run, even if the input is the same. To make it a pure function, you'd have to pass __dirname in as a parameter.

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed this is fine for SO. It may be a simple question (and is probably a dupe), but its not off-topic.

Comment: @JoeClay `__dirname` does not depend on where the function is called, it only depends on where it was defined.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I phrased that poorly, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this function is pure since `__dirname` is a constant. It does not matter at all how that constant did get its value (in this case, during the compilation of the module).